# How can I recognize a rhythmic figure by pressing any key on keyboard

Tags: notation, software, rhythm

Have you got any suggestions about software that can recognize a rhythmic figure after I tapped it on a keyboard? If Logic Pro X can do it, that would be **PERFECT**. I mean after I tapped on <kbd>spacebar</kbd> or any other key it displays the rhythmic notation (that I tapped of course) on my screen.

PS. I don't have a MIDI-controller.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible in Logic but some DAW lets you record keyboard input as MIDI. When that is done you can quantize your recording to get the closest rhythmic figure.

Comment: @JoulinNicolas  Maybe Sibelius lets?

Comment: I don't think so but don't quote me on that. As far as I know it's possible with FL studio. I can only assume that it could be possible on other software. this [link](http://www.dummies.com/software/logic-pro-x/how-to-record-midi-in-logic-pro-x-with-musical-typing/) might be a good start to do what you want on Logic.

Comment: Do you just want the timings of the keypresses, or do you want to be able to represent the time the key was held down?

Comment: You could also just learn to transcribe your rhythms yourself? Then you wouldn't be chained to technology?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution in Logic Pro X. Here are some steps:

> [image]
>
> ### Step 1:
>
> Create a software instrument track.

> [image]
> [image]
>
> ### Step 2:
>
> Change the default piano to drum set.

> [image]
>
> ### Step 3:
>
> Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to open a virtual MIDI-keyboard.

> [image]
>
> ### Step 4:
>
> Click <kbd>R</kbd> button or red circle on the top panel in the middle and tap your rhythm pattern as accurate as you can.

> [image]
>
> ### Step 5:
>
> Export this pattern as MIDI file.

> [image]
>
> ### Step 5:
>
> Open this MIDI in Sibelius (or other tab editor) and you'll get the approximate rhythm pattern that you need.

Comment: Logic Pro itself has a score view. No need to get a score editor involved.